# Bootstrap - floating navbar button right

Tags: html, css, css-float, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the bootstrap navigation bar, but I want to float one of the buttons to the right instead of the left as it already is. Here's the HTML:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="navbar-nav pull-right">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried using `nav navbar-nav navbar-right`, `float:right`, and `pull-right`. I really don't know what else I could do. Any help is appreciated.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2K9Z/)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Create a separate `ul.nav` for just that list item and float that `ul` right.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C2K9Z/1/)

Comment: See my answer below. Bootstrap itself has the class `navbar-right` so if a dropdown is there for such menu, it will align properly.

Answer (score 64):

In bootstrap 4 use:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
```

This will push the navbar to the right. Use mr-auto to push it to the left, this is the default behaviour.

Comment: This works perfectly for me. The item floats right when in fullscreen, and stays inline when shrunk to a dropdown menu so worked for desktop and mobile

Comment: You dont realise how long I searched for this solution ! you are my saviour Henry

Comment: Wow. How is this not the top solution? It's exactly what I was looking for +1

Comment: If you are using a collapsable navbar (as found in mdbootstrap), you may find the ml-auto technique does not work. Adding the class 'justify-content-end' may be needed; <div class="collapse navbar-collapse  justify-content-end">

Comment: this was driving me crazy thanks!

Comment: Note that this would be `ms-auto` if using Bootstrap v5.

Answer (score 51):

You would need to use the following markup. If you want to float any menu items to the right, create a separate `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` with `navbar-right` class to it.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you,it works great for full screen. But it doesn't look ok on mobile view. It would be great to keep it aligned the same as others do with some separator.

Comment: If you wish to separate in mobile view, give custom class and write your styles within conditional media queries.

Answer (score 10):

**Bootstrap 5 (update 2021)**

In Bootstrap 5 (see this question), `ml-auto` has been replaced with `ms-auto` to represent start instead of `left`. Since the Navbar is still based on flexbox, auto margins OR flexbox utility classes are still used to align Navbar content.

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-primary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="" width="150"> <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining *why* this solves the OP's problem, so they can understand your code and use the same thought process in the future instead of just copy/pasting your answer.