# Bootstrap3 and navbar, How can I align this li tag to the right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: transparent; max-height: 40px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 15px;">
            <li class=""><a href="#" class="" style="padding: 15px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" style="color:royalblue;"></i></a></li>

            <li class=""><a href="#" class="" style="padding: 15px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal" style="color:royalblue;"></i></a></li>

            <li class="number_three_li"><a href="#" class="" style="padding: 15px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal" style="color:royalblue;"></i></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I want to align `#number_three_li` to the right-side.

Like From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21544688/6426449), I want to pull it to rhe right.

I saw some post saying `pull-right` in `<ul>` tag works well.

But because I want these `<li>` tags not to be collapsed even width is narrower, that is not the right answer for me.

How can I do this?

```css
        .nav {
            display: flex;
        }
```

```html
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: transparent; max-height: 40px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 15px;">
            <li class=""><a href="#" class="" style="padding: 15px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" style="color:royalblue;"></i></a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#" class="" style="padding: 15px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" style=""></i></a></li>

            <li class="#number_three_li"><a href="#" class="" style="padding: 15px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal" style="color:royalblue;"></i></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: did you try to close the first part with </ul> and then put <ul class="navbar-nav for the numberthree??

Comment: Does this solve you problem: `#number_three_li {position: absolute; right: 0}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use inline-block for the li's instead of flex for the nav ul.  Then float the number_three_li to the right.

```css
.nav {
  //display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav > li { display: inline-block !important; }
.number_three_li { 
  float: right; 
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav>li.number_three_li {
     float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>

</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: transparent; max-height: 40px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 15px;">
            <li class=""><a href="#" class="" style="padding: 15px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" style="color:royalblue;"></i></a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#" class="" style="padding: 15px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" style=""></i></a></li>

            <li class="number_three_li"><a href="#" class="" style="padding: 15px"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal" style="color:royalblue;"></i></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```